# latext. Display the name of chapter in the header

Tags: header, latex

I want to display the name of chapter in the header with latex, for example on the even pages display the name of chapter align the right, and display the name of chapter align left on the odd pages. I used the following latex code:
\fancyhead[LO, RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

But it just displayed the title aligned left.

Could you tell me how to deal with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely using a `oneside` (which is the default if you don't specify anything in terms of -`side` specification) setup for your document. This might be echoed by a warning in your `.log`:

> Package `fancyhdr` Warning: `\fancyhead`'s E option without `twoside` option is use
>   less on input line X.

Add the `twoside` option to your `\documentclass` specification:

```
\documentclass[<options>,twoside]{<class>}
```